# Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/composer-dataproc-dag.py] cannot import name 'email'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I am new to GCP and trying to configure a cloud composer pipeline that can send email on failure.

I have setup a sendgrid email API and have updated my cloud composer environment and have also added project_id and email variables on airflow environment. Variables but I am getting this error:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/composer-dataproc-dag.py] cannot import name 'email'
```

Please have a look at my code and let me know what corrections I can make.

```
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators import email

project_id = models.Variable.get("project_id")
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': models.Variable.get("email"),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Define a DAG (directed acyclic graph) of tasks.
# Any task you create within the context manager is automatically added to the
# DAG object.
with models.DAG(
    # The id you will see in the DAG airflow page
    "dataproc_workflow_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    # The interval with which to schedule the DAG
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),  # Override to match your needs
) as dag:

    start_template_job = dataproc_operator.DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateOperator(
        # The task id of your job
        task_id="dataproc_workflow_dag",
        # The template id of your workflow
        template_id="mywf1",
        project_id=project_id,
        # The region for the template
        # For more info on regions where Dataflow is available see:
        # https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/locations
        region="us-central1",
    )
    email_summary = email.EmailOperator(
        task_id='email_summary',
        to=models.Variable.get('email'),
        subject='testing email service of gcp',
        html_content="""
        Analyzed the Requirements and have created a test POC.Lets see If it works out!
        """
        )
```

I am following the code given for reference [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/51ec8262a8f8dc59d0e882187276329c14c7ed9c/composer/workflows/bq_notify.py).

Comment: Which version of ariflow is it?

Comment: Its the newest version of composer and airflow 
composer-1.16.14-airflow-1.10.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of Ariflow version.

When you take a look into [Airflow 1.10.15 Python API reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/_api/airflow/operators/index.html) there is no `email` module.

It appears since [version 2.0.0](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/_api/airflow/operators/index.html).